# Tex Live 2014 full installation does not have documentation files

Tags: texlive, documentation, texdoc

I installed the Full scheme of Tex Live 2014 with `install-tl` on RHEL 5.  I find that it no longer has the `texdoc`-accessible PDF documentation.  Am I missing something? Or is excluding the documentation a community decision that I was not aware of?

```
$ texdoc amsmath
Sorry, no documentation found for amsmath.
If you are unsure about the name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.

$ texdoc tikz
Sorry, no documentation found for tikz.
If you are unsure about the name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.
```

I think I have my `PATH`s correctly set, because I could compile a past project out-of-the-box.  Anyways, I probably still missed something.

How do I install all the PDF documentation seamlessly?

### UPDATE

The output of `texdoc -f` is:

```
~/personal/local/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texdoc/texdoclib.tlu 0.85
Configuration files are:
    active      ~/personal/local/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
Recommended file(s) for personal settings:
    ~/.texlive2014/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
```

This is a TeX Live 2014 that I installed myself, with a custom installation prefix `~/personal/local`.

### UPDATE (Terminal outputs)

Here is the (failure) output of `texdoc -d tikz`: http://pastebin.com/Sxq25TeA
And here is the (success) output of `texdoc -d latex`: http://pastebin.com/dMC9W7Yh, which I find weird because I get the documentation for KOMA-script.

### UPDATE (Problem solved)

This option had to be enabled:

```
[X] Install macro/font doc tree
```

I don't think a `full` installation scheme is needed.  In my case, I customized the packages and disabled the ones that I do not need (mostly the ones for characters of non-Latin languages).

Comment: What's the output of `texdoc -f`? A full install will surely include the doc parts, there has been no change, AFAIK.

Comment: what tex live are you using?  is it one installed by your system (as linux systems do), or did you install it yourself?  (fwiw, my self-installed, recently updated tex live `texdoc` finds the (huge) pgf doc, no problem.)

Comment: @egreg, I have updated the question in response to your comments

Comment: Does `texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf` exist in the `texmf` tree? (This is the documentation you should get when you do `texdoc tikz`. So the answer will tell you whether the problem is missing documentation or a problem finding the documentation.)

Comment: `texdoc -d aardvark` may be helpful. (Where `aardvark` is some actual package name - I just wanted something `texdoc` definitely wouldn't find to see if it told me anything which might be helpful.)

Comment: @cfr, I have updated the question with pastebin links to the terminal output.

Comment: What do you mean you 'think' you have the paths set correctly?  If you didn't explicitly change them after the install to point to TL2014, then you are quite likely compiling with an older version of TL, either from your system's repositories or another manual install you did in a previous year.  Try somethiing like `which latex` to see what your shell thinks.  On my system, I get: `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/latex`; on yours, I'd expect something like `~/personal/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/latex` (if you are on a 64-bit machine).

Comment: @jon, yes, `which latex` and `which texdoc` point to `~/personal/local/bin/...`, which in turn are symlinks to `~/personal/local/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/...`

Comment: When you installed, did you install the `full` scheme? Though if `texdoc latex` gives you that, something is seriously screwy.

Comment: @cfr, yes, I used the `full` scheme. I did not modify anything, except for the default paper size (A4 -> letter) and unchecked the `macro/font doc tree` and `macro/font source tree`.  Does that have an effect? I did find anything on google that `doc tree` actually refers to the `texdoc` documentation.

Comment: If you unchecked the installation of the documentation, then, yes, that probably is having an effect! Use `tlmgr` to install the `macro/font doc tree`.

Comment: @cfr, all right, the `macro/font doc tree` was the culprit. I needed to install it. I had to do a new install from scratch. Thank you everyone!

Comment: @Kit Rather than edit into the question, please post your solution as an answer. The format of the site works best when the question space is for questions and the answer space is for answers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem solved

This option had to be enabled:

```
[X] Install macro/font doc tree
```

I don't think a `full` installation scheme is needed.  In my case, I customized the packages and disabled the ones that I do not need (mostly the ones for characters of non-Latin languages).

Thanks to everyone who offered their opinions in the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the path for info is missing, something like

```
INFOPATH=/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

I'm using the file `.profile` (not RH, but openSuse) to set pathes for TeX:

```
PATH=/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

---

EDIT:

A comment below is doubtful about the need to set the MANPTH and the INFOPATH. But the texlive documentation as of today (http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html) says:

> **create symlinks in standard directories:**
>       This option (Unix only) bypasses the need to change environment variables. Without this option, TEX Live directories usually have to be added to PATH, MANPATH and INFOPATH

So the answer depends upon some installation options. I don't see any harm done by adding these pathes, but, well, I'm a user, not an IT guy.

Comment: Better not to set `MANPATH` at all. At least, if you are using any recent version of the tools. I'm not sure of the details, but `man` now pulls the path from `PATH` or something. At any rate, I know it is now recommended to leave it empty. On my system `INFOPATH` is also empty. Moreover, I don't think either of these have anything to do with `texdoc`.

Comment: For the record, I have enabled the symlinks option, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Also, I browsed the paths that you were referring to. They're mostly empty.

Comment: @Kit The pathes in my answer refer to my computer. I have no idea where you installed texlive! Please adapt the path!

Comment: @KeksDose, yes, sorry, I adapted the paths according to my installation, of course.

Comment: It can be harmful to set `MANPATH`, at least. Because **you may end up with nothing BUT the TeX Live manpages** if you are using a system where `MANPATH` is configured dynamically (i.e. empty by default). This is because if `MANPATH` is set, it may be used *rather than dynamic configuration`* and if `MANPATH` starts empty, as is now usual, all you will have in your `MANPATH` are the directories you explicitly list i.e. just the TeX Live pages. If the TeX Live docs say otherwise, so much the worse for the docs. Read `man man` for details.

Comment: Moreover `texdoc` does **not search** for either man pages or info pages. It searches the `texmf doc` trees. I'm sorry but this answer is just wrong.

Comment: Note that **if** you make absolutely sure to include a colon before or after the path, you should still be able to find documentation, depending on how `manpath` is configured on your system. I don't know if this works everywhere. But `manpath` will then no longer tell you where manual pages are to be found. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/manpath.1.html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `texdoc` displays documentation from the `doc` trees which are part of the various `texmf` trees on your system. If you opt not to install the `macro/font doc tree` then you are effectively telling `tlmgr` to skip the documentation.

To check this is the problem, run

```
tlmgr option docfiles
```

If the option is set to `0` then you don't have the documentation files installed.

```
tlmgr option docfiles 1
```

will change this option. However, this will not, unfortunately, install documentation for packages already installed. In effect, this means that you can only install the documentation by rerunning the original installer as described in [Kit's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202673/39222).

but I am not entirely certain as I've never opted out of the documentation when installing.

Comment: I actually did this, but I did not "feel" the documentation being downloaded (it was too quick). The documentation folders were empty as well.

Comment: @Kit That's too bad. As I said, I couldn't test this because I didn't disable that option in the first place. I wonder if it is because this option affects only what is installed on a package-by-package basis so that it only affects packages as they get installed or updated in the future, rather than applying also to the documentation for packages you've already installed. If so, I wonder if there is a 'clean' way to get that stuff installed without reinstalling the whole thing.